# How to manage multiple users with EF in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am designing a database for a language learning center. I have 3 subjects to manage: `admin`, `teacher` and `student`.

- `Admin` can assign the role to the other 2 objects
- The `teacher` has the role of posting instructions on the website
- `Students` can register for the course and pay

Should I create a `teacher` and a `student` table in the database? If so - how should I design them? Otherwise how should I manage just one user object?

I designed the `AppUser` class to inherit the identity user class, the student and teacher classes inherit from the `AppUser` class, is that a good approach?

Comment: you're really mixing the 2 fairly different kinds of entity. The `Teacher` and `Student` are 2 business entities and of course should have the corresponding separate tables. The other kind of entity (system entity) can be called `Login` (user login). That can be mapped to the `User` table. Each (user) login has some roles to determine which permissions the associated person (teacher/student) can do. So in this case you may have some preset/init roles (teacher role, admin role, student role) that should always be granted to users associated with the corresponding persons.

Comment: You mean that the AppUser created in the database is for login only, isn't it @Hopeless

Comment: yes exactly. your business models may expand with other kinds of person (not just teacher, student) in future (just assumed so) more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to create a teacher and a student table in the database. Because their roles are completely different, this can separate their respective businesses completely. Reduce the complexity of design.

Create a login page, you can provide a drop-down list for users to choose their own roles, query the database according to the user's role, and then fill the user and the user's role to identity to achieve authentication.

Comment: So should I inherit the identityuser class in the teacher or student class

Comment: Yes, you should inherit the identityuser in the two classes if you separate them.

Answer (score 1):

The question for how to handle this comes down to first separating logic into the "Can do" and "has a" bins.

If your objects have unique relationships, (Lets say Teachers have several Table relations unique to them), then you want to use different tables for them.

If however you can simplify the relations enough that they can be functionally the same (IE both Teachers and Students will have a Classroom relation, which though it means something different for them, can be re-used as the same column for both), then you want to instead handle this difference via Roles.

Roles allow you to apply authorization to various parts of your website.

It might also be best practice to do both of the above.

When handling "multi user type" style interfaces, you typically will need to be careful about selecting how you register users. Do you want to do it via invitation emails/codes? Or perhaps Administrators create the users by hand and there is no form of registration at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AspNetRoles table. And bind it to AspNetUsers table. You don't need to create teacher and students table.